# Posting delegate inside Blocks doesn't work (ASIHTTPRequest)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, asihttprequest, block

I'm having a problem with using delegate inside Blocks.

With ARC on, this is example to show the issue.

```
- (void)whatsGoingOn {

    NSString *address = @"someAddress";    

    //setting for request
    NSURL *requestURL               = [NSURL URLWithString:address];    
    __weak ASIHTTPRequest *request  = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];    

    [delegate_ postDelegateMethod]; //This delegation works fine       

    [request setCompletionBlock:^{     
        [delegate_ postDelegateMethod]; //This delegation doesn't work        
    }];

    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

It seems that I can't post delegation inside Blocks.
What should I do in this situation?

I can use notification instead, but I don't feel that's a good way to go.

This is the head part of the class.
If I don't use weak, the request part will make a retain cycle, so not sure what to do yet.

```
@interface URLFilter : NSObject {
      id __weak                   delegate_;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id                              delegate;


@implementation URLFilter
@synthesize delegate    = delegate_;
```

***SOLVED!!!**

It worked by making another __block id blockDelegate.
And, there is no memory leak either.

```
- (void)whatsGoingOn {

    NSString *address = @"someAddress";    

    //setting for request
    NSURL *requestURL               = [NSURL URLWithString:bitlyAPIAddress];    
    __weak ASIHTTPRequest *request  = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];    

    //set blockDelegate since delegate_ will be gone inside blocks
    __block id blockDelegate        = delegate_;

    [request setCompletionBlock:^{        

        //it works
        [blockDelegate postDelegateMethod];
    }];

    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

**UPDATE**

I looked at the code again, and the issue might be caused by this block method outside of 
that whatsGoingOn method.

Inside of this twitter api block method, I call that whatsGoingOn method, and inside of whatsGoingOn method, I put asihttprequest block method.

Strangely, if I use usual delegate method of asihtttprequest in side of blocks, it crushes, 
that's why I picked up block method of asihttprequest.

```
//request tweet data
[twRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                         NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse,
                                         NSError *error) {
    [self whatsGoingOn];                            
}];
```

Comment: how is delegate_ declared and initialized?

Comment: By the way, where are you actually setting your delegate?

Comment: Yes, it works outside [request setCompletionBlock:^{

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by making another __block id blockDelegate.
And, there is no memory leak either. :)

```
//setting for request
NSURL *requestURL               = [NSURL URLWithString:bitlyAPIAddress];    
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request  = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];    

//set blockDelegate since delegate_ will be gone inside blocks
__block id blockDelegate        = delegate_;

[request setCompletionBlock:^{        

    //it works
    [blockDelegate postDelegateMethod];
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: This means that your delegate was being deallocated before you could use it.  Under ARC, blocks retain __block variables so this guarantees its existence until the end of the block (at least).  Though I'm curious as to why your delegate was being deallocated (it probably went out of scope somewhere).  Therefore, with weak it would be nil and thus APPEAR to never be called, and with assign it would be a dangling pointer and crash.

Comment: Thanks for your help again, I updated the answer.  It might be related to the before that whatsGoingOn method.  Sorry, I didn't realize that before you post the comment.

Comment: @borrrden I see you live in Tokyo, if you come to iOS tokyo meetup in the future, let me buy you a beer. thanks:)

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time. I was using weak pointer to self to call my delegate, which wasn't being called. Now thanks to adding block, it works!

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure that the problem is the __weak qualifier on the request.  If I'm right, you won't get the delegate invocation in the block and you won't get anything else - the request's copy of the block is getting cleaned up before it has a chance to run.

```
- (void)whatsGoingOn {

    NSString *address = @"someAddress";    

    //setting for request
    NSURL *requestURL        = [NSURL URLWithString:address];    
    ASIHTTPRequest *request  = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];    

    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"proof we got here.  delegate = %@", self.delegate);   
        [self.delegate postDelegateMethod]; // This delegation _should_ work        
    }];

    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Comment: But, if I don't use __weak, it causes retain cycle.  I tried __block with retain cycle error message anyway, but somehow it still don't call delegation. :(  Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I don't see the retain cycle.  The block doesn't refer to the request.  Can you post the retain cycle warning?

Comment: Yes, I can. I uploaded the picture. :)

Comment: I see the image.  Yes, there's a retain cycle there, the block refers to the request, but it's not the code you posted.  Delete request=nil; and don't declare request as __weak or __block.  (And while you're at it, declare your delegate as assign, not _weak either.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, I updated the questions based on your advice.  But, I still crush issue on ARC enabled, if I use assign. :(

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more.  Kind of a moving target. You were certainly crashing at first due to the weak qualifier on the request.

Comment: thanks for your helps, I think it works fine with __block.  I updated the question with the working codes.

Answer (score 2):

*NEVER* count on weak references sticking around.  Assuming the request is created inside the method in your code, it will be immediately deallocated before the next line even runs.

With the update, I see the reference cycle.  What you should do is make `request` an iVar.  Then before the block do this:

```
ASIHTTPRequest __weak *weakRequest = mRequest;
```

Then refer to the weak request instead of the strong one.

Comment: Thank you.  Hmm, but if I don't use weak, it causes retain cycle.:(

Comment: Why?  You can break retain cycles manually by setting things to `nil` you know.

Comment: I uploaded the picture of the screen, can you check it out?

Comment: Ah, this will cause request to reference itself, indeed.  The normal way around this is to make your request object an iVar (strong), then create a weak reference to the iVar before the block.  See my edit.

Comment: THanks for your update, but, delegation doesn't work yet.:( I updated the code of the question.

Comment: You didn't do it correctly, you need to make `request` an instance variable, or it will be deallocated at the end of that method.  P.S. you only need to use weakRequest *inside* the block.  It's fine if you use it outside too, but it looks a bit strange ^^.

Comment: Why should he make it an ivar?  He should remove the cyclical reference.  Even if he needed the cyclical ref, he could declare a copy of the request on the stack as _unsafe_unretained, then refer to that in the block.  But the only thing he's doing with the block reference is setting it to nil unnecessarily.

Comment: @danh He is making the original object as a local object in the method.  Under ARC rules, it will be deallocated at the end of that scope.  Since it needs to live on asynchronously, there needs to be at least 1 strong reference to it.  Then he can use weak referencing to link to the existing strong reference.  Why would you encourage him to use assign instead of weak?  That will just create a dangling pointer.  He is doing more than just setting it to nil, he is callin g a method that uses the request as a parameter.

Comment: It will remain allocated.  The URL connection in that http request retains it's delegate.  And where do you see the ref to the request besides the nil assignment?

Comment: @danh Ah, in that case you are correct (but I don't see anywhere where he is setting a delegate for anything).  Also, in the picture he has commented it out, but in the code below he called `[self requestFinished:weakRequest];` which will be `[self requestFinished:request]` without the weak pointer.

Comment: thanks for your helps, I think it works fine with __block.  I updated the question with the working codes.